# Building a ray tracing path-loss propagation model of LTE for small cells (pRRus)

Tags: path-loss

Phones will receive signal from many pRRus. Should I average the antenna gain and all the path-loss (both line of sight and no-line of sight)? Or should I sum them all together?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this asks for channel modeling of a pronouncedly non-amateur radio standard.

Comment: (also, this question shows little understanding of the matter at hand. If you're doing ray tracing, than certainly not for the purpose of ignoring the majority of propagation phenomena, but to actually model them. So, neither averaging nor just summing is right: you're building a ray tracer, so you're tracing rays and adding them up including phase information, probably.)

Comment: So I should add them up????

Comment: no. I explicitly said you should not.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Questions about the technology of radio (amateur or otherwise) are expressly on topic: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MikeWaters absolutely. OP is asking about channel modeling for a very specific, very non-amateur use case. I can't find a way to generalize this to "general technology of radio".

Comment: @MarcusMüller Respectfully, I believe that propagation and path losses are indeed about the **technology of radio**. Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: Because OP is not asking how to generate a propagation simulation, (even if they did, it would be exceedingly broad!), they ask about something that involves the very LTE-specific and actually even network operator-specific aspect of building a coverage map for multi-pico remote radio unit (pRRu) system. AFAIK; pRRu is a huawei-specific term, and the way they orchestrate their pico radio units is proprietary, and leads to a very specific situation, where probably these device are cooperative under some, but uncoordinated in other aspects. This is so deep into LTE- and supplier-specific logic,

Comment: that the "how to build a raytracing map for incoherent same-frequency transmitters" is actually but a small set of the problems – it'd be necessary to understand the logic that is behind how you orchestrate networks of such devices, that the *radio* aspect totally fades in comparison. I *really* don't think "how does my very complex LTE hardware network work in a half-cooperative mode indoors" is a question that has much "general radio technology" applicability.

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I have to calculate the path-loss for reflection. How could I calculate it from more than one antenna?